# Polymorphism wierd Output

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    int bval;
    base(){bval=0;}
};

class deri:public base {
public:
    int dval;
    deri(){dval=1;}
};

void SomeFunc(base*arr,int size) {
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++,arr++) {
        cout<<arr->bval;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
    base BaseArr[5];
    SomeFunc(BaseArr,5);
    deri DeriArr[5];
    SomeFunc(DeriArr,5);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output of the above code this?

00000

01010

When I write

```
SomeFunc(DeriArr,5);
```

What happens? How is the base pointer arr handling the derived object?

Comment: Please include both actual and expected behaviour in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You experience some slicing here. The base class has a size of (lets say) 4 and the derived class a size of 8. Passing an array of derived objects to the function and advancing a base class pointer (by an offset of 4 bytes) yields to the alternating sequence of 0 and 1.

If you want to keep it polymorph you should give your base class a virtual destructor and pass an array of pointers (eg std::shared_ptr) to your function.

**Illustration:**

Having a base object holding one integer:

```
int bval
```

A derived object holding two integers:

```
int bval
int dval
```

And promising a memory location holding consectuive base objects:

```
Offset Value Pointer
 0     0     <- base_pointer
 4     0
 8     0
12     0
16     0
```

But passing a memory location holding consectuive derived objects:

```
Offset Value Pointer
 0     0     <- base_pointer      <- derived_pointer
 4     1     <- base_pointer + 1  
 8     0     <- base_pointer + 2  <- derived_pointer + 1
12     1     <- base_pointer + 3
16     0     <- base_pointer + 4  <- derived_pointer + 2
...
32     0                          <- derived_pointer + 4
36     1
```

And advancing a base pointer by one (which implies an offset of 4 bytes),
but not a derived pointer, yields to the slicing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You said "advancing a base class pointer (by an offset of 4 bytes) yields to the alternating sequence of 0 and 1." How can it alternate? It should either access dval or bval (one of these only). Can you please explain more?

Comment: This "slicing" seems undefined behavior to me.

Answer (score 1):

The base pointer doesn't really handle the derived object. It is legal to address an object by any of its base classes, but once youre in code which is dealing with the base class then it no longer knows it's actually a derived class.

So when you increment the arr pointer, it moves on in memory by the size of 'base'. In reality it should be incrementing by the size of deri, but unfortunately it no longer knows the objects are of type deri.